# Is $C([0,T];C[a,b]) = C([0,T] \times [a,b])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, bochner-spaces

I came across a doubt yesterday. Is the following equality true?? $$C([0,T];C[a,b]) = C([0,T] \times [a,b])$$

I have a feeling that the answer is no.
I know that if $f \in C([0,T];C[a,b])$ then $f \in C([0,T]\times [a,b])$ and in order to prove the other direction, given $f \in C([0,T]\times [a,b])$ we would have to prove that the function $g_t(x) = f(t,x)$ is such that $g_t \in C[a,b]$ for each $t$ and that $$\sup\limits_{t \in [0,T]} \|g_t\|_\infty < \infty.$$

Does anybody know an example that shows that the equality is not true?

Comment: showing the estimate for the supremum is not enough, you must show continuity of $t\mapsto g_t$.

Comment: @Thomas but does it hold? Or my suspicious that it does not hold is correct?

Comment: What topology are you putting on the space $C(a,b)$?

Comment: @Aweygan I edited the question and changed $(a,b)$ to $[a,b]$. Then I consider $C[a,b]$ with the max norm. I am interested in the case $C(a,b)$ with the sup norm too :)

Comment: I would try to use **uniform continuity** for a continuous function on a compact set.  [But that will not work for $C(a,b)$ since some of its functions are unbounded.]

Answer (score 2):

It is true. This is a special case of the *exponential law for function spaces*. See for example [Exponential Law in Algebraic topology.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3339647) and [Exponential Law (Topology) definition query](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2096159). You can find it in most textbooks on general topology (provided they cover functions spaces and the compact-open topology).

However, let us deal with your question as it is. In your question all function spaces are endowed with the $\sup$-metric. I shall comment on the relation between the metric topology and the compact-open topology later.

Let me first suggest to distinguish the functions in $C([0,T];C[a,b])$ and in $C([0,T] \times [a,b])$ notationally. Given $f \in C([0,T];C[a,b])$, we write $\bar f  = e(f) : [0,T] \times [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ for the function defined by $\bar f(t,x) = f(t)(x)$. You say that you already know that   $\bar f$ is continuous, i.e. we have defined a function $e :  C([0,T];C[a,b]) \to C([0,T] \times [a,b])$.

It remains to show that $e$ is bijective. To do so, let us consider $g \in C([0,T] \times [a,b])$. Clearly the maps $i_t : [a,b] \to [0,T] \times [a,b], i_t(x) = (t,x)$, are continuous for all $t \in [0,T]$. Hence the functions $g_t = g \circ i_t : [a,b] \to \mathbb R, g_t(x) = g(t,x)$, are continuous, i.e. we have $g_t \in C([a,b])$. This construction gives us a function $\tilde g  = \bar e(g) : [0,T] \to C([a,b])$. Let us show that $\tilde g$ is uniformly continuous (this is even stronger than showing that $\tilde g$ is continuous). This means that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert s - t \rvert < \delta$ implies $\lVert \tilde g_s -  \tilde g_t \rVert_\infty = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} \lvert g(s,x) - g(t,x) \rvert < \epsilon$. We know that $g$ is uniformly continuous, i.e. there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert s - t \rvert + \lvert x - y \rvert < \delta$ implies $\lvert g(s,x) -  g(t,y) \rvert < \epsilon/2$. Hence $\lvert s - t \rvert < \delta$ implies $\lvert g(s,x) -  g(t,x) \rvert < \epsilon/2$ for all $x$. We conclude $\lVert \tilde g_s -  \tilde g_t \rVert_\infty \le \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$. Thus $\tilde g  \in C([0,T];C[a,b]) $, i.e we have defined a function $\bar e : C([0,T] \times [a,b]) \to  C([0,T];C[a,b])$.

By construction we have $\bar e \circ e = id$ and $e \circ \bar e = id$. Therefore $e$ and $\bar e$ are bijections which are inverse to each other.

What is the relation between this "metric" exponential law and the general exponential law mentioned above? This says that if $X,Y,Z$ are topological spaces and $Y$ is locally compact, then we have a bijection between the function spaces $C(X \times Y,Z)$ and $C(X,C(Y,Z))$, where $C(Y,Z)$ is endowed with the compact-open topology. But is well-known and easy to show that for a compact space $X$ and a metric space $(Y,d)$, the compact-open topology on $C(X,Y)$ agrees with the topology generated by the $\sup$-metric $d_\infty(f,f') = \sup_{x \in X} d(f(x),f'(x))$.

Comment: I appreciate your answer :) Very nice! Would the same remain true if $[a,b]$ was replaced by $(a,b)$?

Comment: It depends on the topology you give to function spaces. Since $(a,b)$ is locally compact, the general exponential law for function spaces with the compact-open topology applies.  But since $(a,b)$ and $[0,t) \times (a,b)$ are non-compact, there exist unbounded real-valued functions and you cannot define the $\sup$-norm.